# importing a cordova android project in to netbeans. Build.xml file cannot be loaded

Tags: android, xml, cordova, netbeans

I imported a cordova project based on HTML5 which was developed by my friend and tried to run it on Netbeans. But when I run it, it says

`cannot find ..\my friend's android sdk path\build.xml imported from ..\my project's path(not my sdk path)\build.xml`

why this problem get to happen and how can I overcome the issue and run the project.

I found a si,iler issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10235882/cannot-find-build-xml-android) and edited local.properties file under the netbeans project\platforms as answered there. But I am still getting the error. help me. thank you ..

Answer (score 1):

1. Have you checked if your path has the 'build.xml'?
   It should be in %SDK%\tools. Like [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10264779/3075174) in the question you linked, maybe you have a bad SDK.

   > check which android version your app is and which versions are available in the SDK. This error is thrown by netbeans if there is no matching SDK version.
2. You need to set your environment variable, like they do [here](https://developer.vuforia.com/resources/dev-guide/step-1-setting-development-environment-android-sdk): (You can use only 'C:\Development\Android\android-sdk-windows', no '\platform-tools\')

   > Add the platform-tools\ directory to your Windows path:  ;C:\Development\Android\android-sdk-windows\platform-tools\